# Thumbnail of Video recorded using mediacapture throwing exception in winrt phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Issue which i am facing is OS takes time to generate thumbnail, if i try to access the thumbnail it is throwing error. Any workaround for this? Can't specify Task.Delay as timings could be different for different phones. I want to show the thumbnail instantaneously.

Comment: Can you post the code with the problem? Is it possible to assign this job to asynchronous Task and check it's result if the tumbnail is ready?

Comment: @Romasz i am using StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync method documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227212.aspx to retrieve the thumbnail after recording video using media capture. I want to know the reason behind it. Asynchronus task is a solution but UX will not be good as user will have to wait for about 2s to get the thumbnail of video just recorded.

Comment: It's hard to say what stays behind *GetThumbnailAsync* method, but surely it will need some time. I'm not sure what you mean by getting error when trying to access the thumbnail. Maybe you can use a special Task which will be run on separate thread and once it finishes, then it will set for example a flag that thumbnail is ready. But it surely will need some time - as I'm playing with some image operations, some of them need more than 2seconds, which will also denepnd on phone model.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really speed up processes that take a while to complete. You're at the mercy of the OS to provide you with the thumbnail when it can, but do make sure that you kick off the request as soon as you can.

Make sure all your processes are asynchronous, and the UI will remain responsive during this call. While it processes, you should be showing some sort of an activity indicator to the user, possibly in the form of a `TextBlock` with the word "Loading..." near a `ProgressRing` that has its `IsActive` property set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Home it will help someone. The below code will generate thumb image for video file

```
           var recordedFile =//get StorageFile

            var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(recordedFile);
            var comp = new MediaComposition();
            comp.Clips.Add(clip);
            var thumbstream = await comp.GetThumbnailAsync(TimeSpan.Zero, 320, 240, VideoFramePrecision.NearestKeyFrame);
```

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition) to get more info about `MediaComposition` class.